# Как происходит проверка email

Tags: php

Как происходит проверка email при регистрации, когда вам нужно пройти по ссылке на вашей почте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто. Когда пользователь регистрируется, для него генерируется некое случайное число/набор символов (назовем КОД). КОД записывается  в базу и отсылается пользователю (например в виде ссылки, куда включен этот КОД и  дополнительная информация - имя).

Когда пользователь получает эту ссылку и кликает по ней, сервер получает КОД и имя пользователя, сверяет по базе. Если все совпадает - значит пользователь верифицирован, отмечаем это в базе.

Если пользователь зашел, а в базе ещё есть код (то есть, он не верифицирован), то можно предложить отправить код верификации ещё раз и/или показывать не весь функционал сайта.

Answer (score 2):

создаем в базе юзера с полем validated = 0 и validate_hash = md5(time().$user_login).
Присылаем на почту ссылку вида

mysite.dev/validate_user.php?hash=$validate_hash

пользователь жмет, меняем в базе validated на 0 и удаляем validate_hash, чтобы повторно ссылка не действовала.

Это вкратце, самый простой вариант